# Forecasting with exogenous variables

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn, forecasting

I have the following time-series data:

```
date        volatility contractType moneyness
2018-01-02  0.656351   A            89.860333
2018-01-02  0.561393   A            91.383390
2018-01-02  0.463378   A            92.958966
2018-01-02  0.361770   A            94.589825
2018-01-02  0.319940   A            95.258304
...         ...        ...          ...
2022-03-10  0.900534   D            120.655385
2022-03-10  0.939075   D            121.960000
2022-03-10  0.976861   D            127.229091
2022-03-10  1.022399   D            138.952000
2022-03-10  1.875746   D            139.760000
```

- Type of contract is categorical (A,B,C,D)
- Moneyness ranges from 50-150, and is continuous. To reduce dimensionality, I could also bin it into ~10 categorical bins.

Which ML model should I use to obtain a trained function  $\hat{f}(date, contractType, moneyness) = volatility $ ?

**I am confused about the type of model and data I should use to obtain a trained function of time, and exogenous variables** $ f(t, x_1, x_2, .. x_n) = y$.

Should $x's$ be categorical ? Can I leave moneyness as continuous?